# jquery selector with context from get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, jquery-selectors

When loading a file with `$.get()` and then selecting its content with `$('*',data)`, it seems to only work when the content is wrapped in at least 2 divs; doesn't work with a single div.

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/mishka00/1x7Lvm8t. Clicking Test1 displays SUCCESS as the content is wrapped in two divs; Test2 doesn't display anything. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(selector, context)` is same as `$(context).find(selector)`. Since the second collection doesn't have any descendant elements the collection is empty and `text` returns an empty string.

In other words, In both snippets the wrapper element of the collection is a `div` element. In the first snippet the wrapper element of the collection has a descendant `div` element but the second element has no descendants.

```
// the first snippet
$('*', data) // => $("<div>Success</div>")
// the second snippet
$('*', data) // => $()
```

If you just pass the `data` to the jQuery constructor then both of the snippets will return `"SUCCESS"`.